# Inkscape: How to write text on anchor path

Tags: inkscape, text

I have some circles. I want to write text inside them but the text path needs to be circle also not straight. How can I do this in inkscape?
[image]

Comment: Are you meaning [Text on path](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Text-Path.html) command?

Comment: @Paolo Gibellini I do not know what path command is. I mean text not on a straight line but on curves like following a circle shape.

Comment: Have you tried to follow the link in my comment?

Answer (score 1):

In Inkscape, type some text. Then draw a circle. Select both the circle and text.  Then click *Text > Put on Path.*

This will put the text on the circle. You can move it around the circle by choosing the circle tool, and moving the start and end points. The text will also still be editable, so you can select it, type new text, or change the font.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Create the text and and a circle section of the right size outside your final painting
- transform the object (circle) to path (path menue)
- transform the text to path (path: stroke to path)
- select all characters and group them together
- select textgroup and circle
- from menue extensions, choose "generate from path", "pattern along path"
- in the dialog choose Copy: Single, Style Snake

Resize and rotate your text, if neccessary, and move it into your image to right place. [image: 5 steps pattern to path]

In the sample image, the path was to small for the text. Therefore the "h" is deformed. If this happens to your work, select a smaller font and redo from there or a bigger circle section.